# How can I set a page in the shell flyout to only load once logged in?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I am trying to create a flyout menu with the logged-in users profile picture in the header. I use an api to get the url to the profile pic, but this can't happen until the user is logged in.

Using AppShell, it seems the flyout content is created as soon as the app runs, so it can't get the data it would need for the profile picture. I tried binding to the `IsLogged` property (but not sure I implemented that correctly), but it seems it's still runs the code on the page even when `IsLogged` is false.

How can I get this header section to only try to get the picture if the user is logged in?

AppShell.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:fontAwesome="clr-namespace:FontAwesome"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DOTS.Views"
   xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:DOTS.Controls"
   xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
   Title="DOTS"
   x:Class="DOTS.AppShell">

<Shell.FlyoutHeader>
    <controls:FlyoutHeader IsVisible="{Binding IsLogged}"/>
</Shell.FlyoutHeader>

<!-- Login/Start Page -->
<ShellItem Route="LoginPage" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}"/>
</ShellItem>
```

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    public bool IsLogged
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsLoggedProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsLoggedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsLoggedProperty =
BindableProperty.Create("IsLogged", typeof(bool), typeof(AppShell), false, propertyChanged: IsLogged_PropertyChanged);

    private static void IsLogged_PropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
      if ((bool) newValue)
   Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");
else
  Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(LoginPage)}");

  }
```

FlyoutHeader.xaml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="DOTS.Controls.FlyoutHeader">
  <ContentView.Content>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
        <ImageButton x:Name="ProfilePic" WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="80" CornerRadius="40"  HorizontalOptions ="Center" Clicked ="UpdateProfile_Clicked" />
    </Grid>
</ContentView.Content>
```

FlyoutHeader.xaml.cs

```
  namespace DOTS.Controls
  {
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class FlyoutHeader : ContentView
    {
      public FlyoutHeader()
       {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetProfilePic();
      }

      public void GetProfilePic()
      {
        ProfilePic.Source = (string)Application.Current.Properties["picUrl"];
       //This value is set upon login
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AppShell, upon `IsLogged` value change to true, call the `GetProfilePic()` method:

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    public bool IsLogged
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsLoggedProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsLoggedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsLoggedProperty =
BindableProperty.Create("IsLogged", typeof(bool), typeof(AppShell), false, propertyChanged: IsLogged_PropertyChanged);

    private static async void IsLogged_PropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
      if ((bool) newValue)
      {
         await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");
         (Current.FlyoutHeader as FlyoutHeader)?.GetProfilePic();
      }

      else
         await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(LoginPage)}");
  }
```

In `FlyoutHeader.xaml.cs` do a test on `IsLogged`:

```
namespace DOTS.Controls
  {
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class FlyoutHeader : ContentView
    {
      public FlyoutHeader()
       {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetProfilePic();
      }

      public void GetProfilePic()
      {
        if ( (Shell.Current as AppShell).IsLogged)
             ProfilePic.Source = (string)Application.Current.Properties["picUrl"];
       //This value is set upon login
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It does not like the Shell.Current.IsLogged call on FlyoutHeader.xaml.cs.
Error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'Shell' does not contain a definition for 'IsLogged' and no accessible extension method 'IsLogged' accepting a first argument of type 'Shell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Yea forgot to cast to AppShell please try with my last update

Comment: It does not load the FlyoutHeader at all, once logged in.

Comment: Does it navigate to MainPage once logged in ? Also you need to await the async call GoToAsync()

Comment: Yes, but that is because of the LoginPage. When I take the navigation out of the Login Page, it actually still goes to the correct page. I commented out the gotoasync's in if ((bool) newValue) and put in console.writelines of true or false. Neither the true or false are being written to the console.

Comment: Since I don't know how/where you are setting `IsLogged`. Could you confirm that `IsLogged_PropertyChanged()` is being triggered when you log in and what is the value of `newValue` ?

Comment: I was missing

<Shell.FlyoutHeader>
    <controls:FlyoutHeader IsVisible="{Binding IsLogged}"/>
</Shell.FlyoutHeader>

in my appshell.xaml. It is working now. Thank you so much!!!